# How to reach data within Iron Router?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

On my page, which has the url `object/:_id`, the user should normally be accessing just one document, which I have set up like so:

```
waitOn: function() {

    return Meteor.subscribe('objects', this.params._id),
},

data: function() {
    return Objects.findOne({_id: this.params._id})
}
```

However, it should also be possible to take a peek at and work with some other objects, **but only those of the same color as the object we're looking at**, so I need to have those accessible as well.

Here's what I thought would work:

```
onBeforeAction: function() {
    var self = Objects.findOne({_id: this.params._id})
    var color = self.color
    Session.set('chosenColor', color)
    this.next()
},

waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('objects', Session.get('chosenColor'))
},

data: function() {
    return Objects.findOne({_id: this.params._id})
}
```

It should be noted that this worked at first, but then suddenly and inexplicably stopped working. `self` is now always "undefined" for some reason.

What is a correct way to access this data within Iron Router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got circular logic here: you're trying to load an object and get its color *before* you subscribe to the collection that's going to publish the object. Just move the color logic to the publishing function on the server.

**client js:**

```
waitOn: function() {

    return Meteor.subscribe('objects', this.params._id);
},

data: function() {
    return Objects.findOne({_id: this.params._id})
}
```

**server js:**

```
Meteor.publish('objects',function(id){
  check(id, Meteor.Collection.ObjectID);
  var self = Objects.findOne({_id: id})
  if ( self ){
    var color = self.color;
    return Objects.find({ color: color });
  }
  else this.ready();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with a `this.ready()` condition in data:

```
waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('objects');
},

data: function() {
    if (this.ready()) {
        var self = Objects.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
        var color = self.color;

        return Objects.findOne({_id: this.params._id}, color);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, and I don't want the data context to be all of those objects in that color.